# How to retrieve data using a db connector in ESB

Tags: mule, esb, anypoint-studio

[image]

I am trying to retrieve names of employees from the database by calling a stored procedure and logging it.
But Instead of the names , this is the output of the log:

```
INFO  2019-12-11 11:48:39,994 [[MuleRuntime].cpuLight.10: [testrun].testrunFlow.CPU_LITE @3bc66a50] [event: 0-12970c00-1bde-11ea-92a5-38dead78b440] org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: 
org.mule.runtime.core.internal.message.DefaultMessageBuilder$MessageImplementation
{
  payload=org.mule.extension.db.internal.result.statement.CloseableMap@8194c34
  mediaType=application/java; charset=UTF-8
  attributes=<not set>
  attributesMediaType=*/*
}
```

what changes can I make so that I recieve the list of names from db.

Comment: what sort of database are you connecting to ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your database connector by defaults returns a resultset. convert your resultset into a json by adding a transformer after DB call and set output type to json. if you want only one particular field then you need to have your transform done accordingly

[image]

[image]

as you can see in your logger that its mentioned the payload type 
payload=org.mule.extension.db.internal.result.statement.CloseableMap@8194c34

that is the internal representation of the result set read back from the stored procedure. so just convert it into json or whatever format you want. Put a transform message component after DB call and do the following:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload
```

if you want any particular field or something then you can see how your payload is getting structured and do the dataweave accordingly

Comment: can you please answer this question also ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59318278/validation-of-payload-in-esb. I would appreciate any help. Thanks.